# How to summarize the elements of std::set

Tags: c++, sum, numeric, stdset, accumulate

I'm trying to find the sum of elements in a set and I was wondering what are good ways to find it. 
I built two classes, one called Customer and one called Item, I want to write a function that will calculate the total payment a customer needs to pay for his products listed in a std::set from the type Item.
Here is the decleration of my set:

```
set<Item> _items;
```

The class Item:

```
private:
    string _name;
    string _serialNumber; //consists of 5 numbers
    int _count=0; //default is 1, can never be less than 1!
    double _unitPrice; //always bigger than 0!
```

Function in the class Item to summarize the price of an item:

```
double Item :: totalPrice() const
{
    return _count*_unitPrice;
}
```

Here is the function I'm trying to write that will sum all of my elements:

```
#include <numeric>
#include "Customer.h"
double Customer::totalSum() const
{
    double sum = std::accumulate(_items.begin(), _items.end(), 0.0);
    return sum;
}
```

But I get this error: `error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::plus<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'`

Improtant note: The class Customer already includes the header of Item.

EDIT: Added information about the class item.

Comment: What's an `Item`? If it's a class and not just a `typedef double` or similar you need to tell the compiler how to add two of them together.

Comment: You have to tell how to add `Item` one to another

Comment: It's a class, pretty sure I mentioned it above.

Comment: @Jokerah: Yeah, but how do you get the price of an `Item`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Item` is something like this:

```
struct Item {
    double price;
};
```

Then you can use the following:

```
auto add_item_price = [](double sum, const Item& item) {
    return sum + item.price;
};

double sum = std::accumulate(_items.begin(), _items.end(), 0.0, add_item_price);
```

[Here's a functional demo](http://ideone.com/bnzAJT).

Explanation:

[`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) lets you provide a function/functor that will do the accumulation. The code I've posted uses a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to do the accumulation. If you aren't using C++11, you can use a regular function instead of a lambda function.

**Avoid overloading `operator+` for `Item`**. Adding two `Item`s doesn't make much sense.

Comment: There is a problem with the line return sum + item.price because price is private in my class, so I can't access it outside of it

Comment: @Jokerah: Then call `item.totalPrice()` or whatever other method you would use to normally get the price of an `Item`. The code doesn't require you to literally write `item.price`. You can replace `item.price` with whatever the appropriate method is to get the item's price.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally happens when compiler doesn't know how to accumulate your type. i.e It should know how to add `Item` type.
So you should overload `+` operator in your `Item` class. 

 Or you have to supply a 4th argument `binary_op`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an `operator+()` for your `Item` type.

Also note that you need an `operator<()` to put `Item` objects into an `std::set` because it is an associative container that needs to be able to compare its objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

struct Item
{
    Item(double price) : m_price(price) {}

    friend double operator+(const Item &lhs, const Item &rhs)
    {
        return lhs.m_price + rhs.m_price;
    }

    friend double operator<(const Item &lhs, const Item &rhs)
    {
        return lhs.m_price < rhs.m_price;
    }

    double m_price;
};

int main ()
{
    std::set<Item> _items;
    _items.insert( Item(10) );
    _items.insert( Item(20) );
    double sum = std::accumulate(_items.begin(), _items.end(), 0.0);
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sum = 30
```

Comment: I have implemented operator < and > and also operator == :)

Comment: Overloading `operator+` sounds fishy. Also, overloading `operator<` is probably not the ideal choice (should it compare price? stock count? name? something else?). `std::set` lets you provide a functor for comparing and sorting the items; use that instead of introducing `operator<` (since it's not really clear what `operator<` should be comparing).

Comment: @Cornstalks: it sounds sensible; overloading operators was the most straightforward way to have a running example though.

Comment: @Cornstalks My operators are comparing the item's serial number, so that's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you get results from the compiler not knowing how to add two objects of type `Item` together during the call to [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Easiest solution is to use the overload of [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) that takes a fourth parameter that specifies a lambda functor to use in place of the default [`std::plus<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) function object.

```
double Customer::totalSum() const {
    return std::accumulate(_items.begin(), _items.end(), 0.0,
        [] (double previousValue, const auto& item) { // Called for every element.
            return previousValue + item.totalPrice();
        });
}
```

Another solution is to create a custom overload for `operator+` that can add two `Item` objects.

```
double operator+(const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs) {
    return lhs.totalPrice() + rhs.totalPrice();
}
```

This can, however, be a bit confusing as the class `Item` has multiple members that are numbers and it is not obvious how an addition should take place. Use great care when overloading arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one who thought about using simple loop ?

```
auto sum = 0.0;
for (const auto& item : items){
   sum += item.m_price;
}
```

can you ask any simpler than that?